# Is it possible to use gradle to develop scala projects?

Tags: scala, gradle, sbt

I'm using sbt to build scala projects, but it always seems too <s>complex</s>(unfamiliar) and heavy to me. I'm also using gradle to build java projects, and which makes me happy.

I wonder is it possible to use gradle to build scala projects? Is there any big scala projects that uses gradle?

Some of my friends just tell me "Never ever think of using gradle for scala project", but refused to tell me the reason.

Comment: The answer is yes. The real question is, since everyone is using sbt, why would you?

Comment: I can't understand you comment. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You can build Scala with Gradle. However, most people use SBT and are familiar with building Scala using that tool. You should really find out what the trade-offs are in terms of community support, tool integration, etc.

Comment: Be careful pinning "complex" onto sbt.  I'd argue it's less complex than gradle.  The word you should use is "unfamiliar".  Not only is sbt quite different from other build tools, it requires some non-entry-level Scala skills.  I've used both tools in the past and I greatly prefer sbt for both my Scala and Java projects.

Comment: Thank you, yes, "unfamiliar" is a better word

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's quite easy to use Gradle with Scala.
We did it for a long time (a mixed team of Java, Groovy and Scala developers) and have been quite happy with it.
Most things work quite well out of the box.

More about Gradle with Scala:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

There are some problems/downfalls though:

- Mixed code compilation when depending on Scala code from Java in mixed code projects. (Some configuration and it will work, but not out of the box)
- More configuration for Scala-specific tools needed than with sbt
- Integration of some Scala tools like *Scalastyle* or *scct* is not possible yet
- no *sbt console* (Gradle console has not been working properly since the last time I checked)
- adding the Scala version number to artifacts has to be added manually each time (no `%%` as in sbt)

Comment: Practical experiences are always precious

Comment: It is possible to use scalastyle from gradle, see https://github.com/MansurAshraf/gradle-scalastyle-plugin

Comment: I submitted a request for better cross-build support in Gradle Scala plugin: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/998

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely possible. Gradle's Scala support is documented in the "Scala plugin" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html). The plugin is used by big companies on big projects, and can be configured to use the same incremental Scala compiler as sbt. So best try for yourself and see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: The link in Peter's answer is the link to the Scala plugin's manual. For a short (7-minute) guide that shows you how to quickly set up a Scala project with Gradle, see here: https://guides.gradle.org/building-scala-libraries/