# Gradle - How to apply plugin configurations on specific sub-projects?

Tags: scala, gradle, build

I have a mixed Java/Scala Maven multi-project that I want to migrate to Gradle.

Some of the sub-projects have only Java code, some have only Scala code and some have both. Applying the java plugin on any of these seem to work fine, but trying to apply the Scala plugin on the projects without Scala code fails due to a missing dependency (the Scala language), which makes sense.

Now, I wish to apply the Scala plugin on for specific sub-projects. Not only that, I need to also apply the following configurations, since some of my Java code depends on Scala code:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "src/main/java"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
```

I also need this to be executed **before** the java plugin executes (as it will fail otherwise).

I do not want to copy these lines to each of the specific Scala sub-projects, but only to add a simple property in their build files (or something similar). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could put these lines into a separate `.gradle` file, and then use `apply from: myScalaStuff.gradle` in each file.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That works, and that's actually my preferred way so far. Could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in your top level `build.gradle`:

```
  subprojects {
     ...
     if(file("src/main/scala").directory) { // or whatever condition you want to use
       apply plugin: 'scala'
       // This seems like a very weird thing to do ... 
       // Assuming, you know what you are doing 
       sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "src/main/java"
       sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
     }
     ...
  }
```

Comment: Nice trick :) I'd actually rather avoid these magic tricks and make this more explicit so it'll be more clear to others who join the project and aren't necessarily all that familiar with Groovy. Regarding the `sourceSets`, I actually looked it up in order to solve the problem of not being able to import Scala code from a Java class by default, and I think I get why it works; it disables the compilation of the Java plugin and lets the Scala one compile the Java file as well (as it handles the mix of the two better).

Comment: I am not sure what your question was about then. You either use "magic tricks" or explicitly spell out sub-project-specific things in sub-project's build files. Your question sounded like the latter was exactly what you wanted to avoid ... Now, you seem to _also_ want to avoid the former :)

Comment: I merely wanted to define some sort of behavior that will only apply to explicitly tagged / annotated sub-projects. Doesn't seem all that magical to me :)

Comment: I get that. So, what about `if(explicitlyTagged) { someSortOfBehavior }` does not qualify as "some sort of befhavior that will only apply to ..."?

Comment: My problem is not with the `if` statement, but rather with the implicit inclusion of this behavior on sub-projects according to their file-system structure instead of their build file.

Comment: Did you miss the comment I put in the code snippet, perhaps? 
`or whatever condition you want to use` ...

Comment: That was my first try... using `if (it.hasProperty('scala')) { // apply scala plugin }` inside the `subprojects` section, and then adding `ext.scala = 'true'` in the specific build files, but it seemed that the property was set only after the code in `subprojects` was executed.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer. You could try `afterEvaluate`, but I think, scala plugin is buggy that way, it won't create the tasks after the project is already evaluated. Frankly, if you don't mind having to modify every affected build file anyway, I don't really see much difference between `ext.scala = true` and `apply plugin: scala`, so ...

Comment: Yeah well I have a few extra lines per scala project, not just the `apply plugin: scala` :/

Comment: Like I said, I don't think you should need those. Scala plugin should handle java sources "out of the box".  And either way, you can still have them with `afterEvaluate` (so that the property is set by then), it's only scala plugin, that's quirky about that.

Comment: It doesn't support mixed projects where Java code depends on Scala code (not out of the box, that is) -
 take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23424560/114626. Since I asked this question I had even more lines added in order to solve a bug with the plugin not running Zinc and Scala 2.11 properly (https://github.com/typesafehub/zinc/issues/87).

Comment: You should be able to do that with `afterEvaluate`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do project filtering, as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:project_filtering).
So, in a nutshell:

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name == 'myScalaProject'}) {
    // Scala projects specific settings
}
```

Of course, since Gradle uses Groovy syntax, you could put those project names in a list and do `contains` or whatever instead of this simple `==` condition.

Comment: That'll work, but I don't want to manage a list of the projects that use scala; instead, i'd rather "annotate" each project individually in its own build file. Is there a way for this method to execute before the compilation for projects that has a specific property? I tried using `ext` and `it.hasProperty()`, but it seems as if the `ext` in the sub-project gets executed after the `configure`.